# Voltage regulator output signal becomes noisy when connected to a CPU

Tags: voltage-regulator, noise, switching-regulator

I am currently working on a PCB where it has two onboard voltage regulators. the first one makes V1in=20 V to V1out= 5.5 V. The second voltage regulator makes V2in=5.5 V to V2out=3.3 V.

The 3.3 V voltage regulator used is [171033801](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/171033801.pdf) from Würth Elektronik. The output from the 5.5 V voltage regulator is stable regardless of the load on the 3.3 V voltage regulator.

The observations:

1. When no load is connected, the voltage regulator produces a stable 3.3 V output as observed in the first oscilloscope image.
2. When the CPU is connected to the PCB, the 3.3 V output becomes really noisy as seen in the second image.
3. There is a previous iteration of the board where another voltage regulator was used. The above issue doesn't present itself there.
4. The data sheet stated that it can provide up to 3 A output signal. When connecting the voltage regulator output to an electronic load, while increasing the load slowly, we could get only 0.7 A output load current until the voltage regulator shut off.
5. When switching the electronic load ON-OFF-ON, the load generates peaks in the current. The voltage regulator can only supply 0.5 A without turning off.
6. We tried giving up to 34 V as input voltage so as to see if we can get the total 3 A current. We could only measure 1 A at the output.

[image: 3V3 voltage regulator schematic.]

[image: Output from Voltage Regulator when CPU is not connected]

[image: Output from Votlage Regulator when CPU is connected]

It's difficult to tell in this image, but on the top are the input capacitors, three of them (47 µF, 2 x 4.7 µF), followed by a 1 µF cap, and the voltage divider resistor that sets the output voltage. To the right is the 5.6 kΩ resistor which sets the switching frequency and to the bottom is the 47 µF output capacitor. I am also adding the 3D model to make it a little easier to understand.

[image: Voltage regulator with polygon pours(-UB -> GND)]

[image: Voltage regulator 3D model]

I have also tested the PCB with three more voltage regulators since then, two from eval boards from Würth Electronic ([178021501](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/178021501.pdf)), this has Vin = 10 V but produces 3.3 V) and the [178023801](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/178023801.pdf). This has the same voltage regulator type but produces 2 A instead of the 3 A that is on the board.

I have also tried using the [L5973D](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l5973d.pdf) on a separate PCB, and in all three cases I have connected the output to the output cap of the voltage regulator (voltage regulator removed) and they work with no noise on either of the voltage lines(5.5 V and 3.3 V) and the CPU starts up.

I have some new voltage regulator, the same kind that is present on the PCB, I will replace these regulators and see if that helps.

I am beginning to think this maybe a faulty regulator, but that just seems like a easy explanation and im not satisfied with it. The reason for this is because I have 30 PCBs which produce different results when hooked up to a power supply. Some do not produce any output i.e., output is 0 V, some produce a sawtooth-like waveform at about 600-900 mV, and the others produces the above type of noise when the CPU is connected.

This makes no sense since if this was a routing issue, it should not work with the other voltage regulators. I would need a second opinion before I write this off as a faulty regulator.

Edit:
I havent come around to doing the testss with regards to what @Deam Franks mentioned, but it seems close to what i think might be happening. I spoke to a person from Würth Elektronik, and he said that there might be some paraitic impedance or transient effect due to the ground planes on the input caps being a seperated and connected only through a via. He also inclined towards maybe a input filtering problem. This makes sense but it doesnt really explain why it works upto 0.5A - 0.7A and stops working after. When i connect a USB to supply the PCB, it introduces alot of noise on the output 3v3 and the input 5v voltage rails. Sometimes I also get 0.85V which is approximately the same as when no feedback from the volatge divider. He said there might be also be a problem by having cold solder points, or something might have gone wrong in the manufacturing process but cannot be sure. He will come next week and give it a once over.

Comment: I have nothing but very bad experience of using pre-made modules like this, even when picking supposedly premium/quality brands. I wouldn't invest a lot of time in trouble-shooting it, just assume that the module is trash. That has been the case every time I've tried one myself - done the mistake at least 3 times by now and we always ended up rolling out our own design instead.

Comment: EmeraldMonk - Hi, Please add the PCB layout corresponding to that supplied part of the schematic. Also, can you replace that schematic image with a higher-resolution (i.e. larger dimension) version? It's *just* too small to make reading easy, at least  with my old eyes. TY

Comment: Try brute force filtering, e.g., 0.47 µF *ceramic* and 470 µF electrolytic capacitors in parallel with the existing 47 µF cap, and, if that is insufficient, add a series inductor before the caps.

Comment: What filter caps are installed on the supply pin of the CPU?

Comment: Do you have the bottom slug (pin13) soldered to ground plane? It is not "noise", your converter just does not operate well and does not hold the intermittent load.

Comment: @SamGibson, i have changed the schematic, I hope its more readable now. if its not readable still i'll try to find a way to upload the schematic.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I tried doing that after reading your comment, Actually put 470µF and 470nF at output and 2x100µF at the input. I was still able to observe the 'Noise' on both the 3v3 and 5v5 voltage lines.

Comment: @Fredled, I have 3x10µF and a 100nF ceramic capacitors at the input of the CPU.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, Yes the bottom pin 13 is soldered to the Ground plane.

Comment: If you are measuring the supply at the CPU itself, and seeing those dips, then you should put extra ceramic bypass caps right there, at the CPU. If this is being measured close to the regulator output, and bypass caps there don't help, then the regulator itself is rubbish. A clue is that it's happening every 25ms, which makes me suspect insufficient bypassing at the CPU itself, and across whatever load is being switched at 25ms intervals.

Comment: @SimonFitch I have measured directly at the output of the Voltage regulator. I have tried increasing the output capacitors, like i mentioned in the above comment to 470µF, 470nF, and 47µF and still get the same noise, although being at a much larger interval. I am begining to suspect maybe faulty Voltage regulators since i have 30 PCBs with the same voltage regulator and none of them have the same output. Some do not work, some have saw tooth waveform at 600-900mV and the rest have this type of waveform.

Comment: What does the input to that regulator look like in the high noise state and when it shuts off?  If your noise occurs at very light loads, it could be because of cycle skipping at light load.

Comment: Did you write to Wurth?

Comment: Does your layout follow Wurth evaluation boards?

Comment: @DeanFranks, Yes i saw similar 'noise' at the input as the output. Although it doesnt dip that much as the output does. The load is about 0.45A stable, with small peaks to 0.7A. But the regulator should do about 3A.

Comment: @Fredled yes i wrote and spoke to a field application engineer, that was the reason i got the evaluation board with the same voltage regulator on it, and also a few voltage regulators as spare which I hope to replace today.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, the layout is as close to the one in the datasheet as i could do it. Although I havent put any shielding vias in the pours.

Comment: Maybe the vias are too small and too few. As I can see they are really tiny vias. (maybe)

Comment: If you see similar noise at the input, put a resistor in series (before the input caps on the second regulator) and see if there is more noise on the source or sink end of the resistor (or the same).  At 0.45A you should not be in pulse skipping.  If you put in a series resistor, put one on the output too and probe (differentially) across the resistors to measure the current waveform with the noise waveform.  If they are synchronous, you have a transient response / filtering issue.  If they are mostly uncorrelated you might have a switching or input filtering problem.